# insert meteor data to external mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have 2 droplets on digitalocean: one running meteor and other running MongoDB. I want to store the data in MongoDB on other droplet instead of meteor's MongoDB. I was able to login via shell via `mongo ip_address:27017/eTable -u uName -p passwd` command. Also I managed to successfully connect to the external database by setting `MONGO_URL` variable, but I am not able to insert data into the external database. I tried different variations with the insert query, but no luck. How can I do this?

**EDIT:**

I don't get any errors. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
var database = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver("mongodb://uname:passwd@ip:27017/eTable");
eTable = new Mongo.Collection('eTable', {
     _driver: database
});
```

And here is the code with which I am trying to insert:

```
Template.intro.rendered = function() {
     db.eTable.insert({
         _id: sess,
         visit: 'True',
         Navigate: 'False',
         Created: 'False',
         Drops: 'False',
         Uploads: 'False',
         ts: new Date()
     }, function(err, data) {
         if (err) {
             console.log(err);
         } else {
             console.log("Inserted");
         }
     });
 }
```

Comment: Errors? current code pieces? are you able to SELECT from that external database?

Comment: Could you please try to use `eTable.insert(doc);` instead of `db.eTable.insert(doc);`? Furthermore, please note that `Template.myTemplate.rendered` is deprecated, use [`Template.myTemplate.onRendered`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered) instead.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: MongoInternals is not defined. This was the error which I was not noticing.Placing the database connection code inside if (Meteor.isServer) {} block solved the issue.Thanks for all the help.